# Saving paragraph of text to mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am doing a project using php and mysql(i am new to this), now i have to store paragraph of text to my database(in a table, for a column).

I tried `"varchar(5000)"` when creating the table but it doesn't allow me.
so please give me a solution for this.

Answer (score 2):

> In MySQL 5.0.3 and later, a CHAR length greater than 255 is illegal and fails with an error

use `text`

```
create table t (long_field text);
```

`text` can store up to 65,535 characters.

Comment: Varchar length can be up to 255 before MySQL 5.0.3, and up to 65,535 in 5.0.3 and later versions.

Comment: Text can for sure store more than 65.535 characters in TEXT data type.

Comment: @AlenOblak: Wrong. Did you not read the doc I refered to? The data type lenghts are mentioned at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 2):

Your mysql field type should

```
TEXT or BLOB
```

Here mysql link which give more idea about data type

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html