# What kind of data type should I use for long contents?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I am creating a project that will hold long text.Probably paragraphs...Now what data type should I use for my datatable fields? I am using mySQL workbench...thanks

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html

Comment: refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12552035/saving-paragraph-of-text-to-mysql)

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL TEXT vs BLOB vs CLOB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7071662/mysql-text-vs-blob-vs-clob)

Comment: I tried to use the longtext then I manually added my question above...error like "data too long" has been encountered. Why?

Answer (score 5):

I believe `TEXT` should be appropriate here, unless you are storing binary data. For binary data use `BLOB`.

Comment: I tried to use the longtext then I manually added my question above...error like "data too long" has been encountered. Why?

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation: [all possible string types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-types.html).

For long texts, `TEXT` is most suitable.

Comment: I tried to use the longtext then I manually added my question above...error like "data too long" has been encountered. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Depends how long "long" is. For quite long (greater than 64K), `text` is the weapon of choice, but won't perform as well as `varchar`, so choose varchar if you know its limit is less than 64K

This [article](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?24,105964,105964) describes the pros and cons of text vs varchar

Answer (score 0):

MySQL VARCHAR size limit is 65535 bytes, and depending on encoding of the column, one char requires 1-4 bytes. If that is not long enough,  you can use TEXT type.

> "The maximum size of a BLOB or TEXT object is determined by its type,
>   but the largest value you actually can transmit between the client and
>   server is determined by the amount of available memory and the size of
>   the communications buffers."

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/blob.html

Answer (score 0):

VARCHAR(0 to 65635 bytes),
TEXT( 0 to 65535 bytes),
BLOB (0 to 65535 bytes),
MEDIUNTEXT(maximum length of 16,777,215 characters),
MEDIUMBLOB(maximum length of 16,777,215 characters),
LONGTEXT(maximum length of 4,294,967,295 characters),
LONGBLOB (maximum length of 4,294,967,295 characters)